Try to exhibit PDF but didn't show
I want to exhibt a PDF file in a tk window but the window is not opening and no Exception is raised
import tkinter as tk
from tkPDFViewer import tkPDFViewer as pdf


cur_file='PPC_Bach.Eng_.-de-Computacao_AGES_Jacobina.pdf'


try:
    newWindow = tk.Tk()
    pdf.ShowPdf().pdf_view(newWindow,pdf_location=cur_file,width=75,height=100).pack()
except Exception as e:
    print(e)


I don't really feel that comfortable working with tkinter but what would happen if you saved pdf.ShowPdf().pdf_view(newWindow,pdf_location=cur_file,width=75,height=100) to a variable and then packed it?

You need to call newWindow.mainloop() after pdf.ShowPdf().pdf_view(...).pack().  However tkPDFViewer is not compatible with latest PyMuPDF and you will get exception.  Use tkPDFViewer2 instead.
